# React - Passing State Back to Parent - UseContext

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-context

I have a MetaTable Component that has LeftSidePanel wrapped with the UseContext.  I want to open the panel when button is click on the MetaTable (passing some data to show detail of a particular record).  My code works to open the Panel but when **I click outside it doesn't close**.I think I would need to set the State back on the parent.  Tried a few things but failed. Any guidance please?

**MetaTable Component**

```
    export const DrawerDataContext = createContext();
    export const DrawerContext = createContext();
    
    const [isDrawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState();
    const [bookId, setBookId] = useState({});
    
    const toggleSidePanel = (row) => {
        setBookId(row)
        setDrawerOpen(true);
    
      }
    
    ... <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>
                          <Stack spacing={0}>
                            <Typography variant="body2" my={0}>
                              {row}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="body2" my={0}>
                              {row}
                            </Typography>
                          </Stack>
                          <Stack spacing={2}>
                            <button onClick={() => { toggleSidePanel(row); }} >toggle drawer</button>
                          </Stack>
                        </TableCell>...
    
    
    <DrawerDataContext.Provider value={bookId}>
            <DrawerContext.Provider value={isDrawerOpen} >
              <LeftSidePanel />
            </DrawerContext.Provider>
          </DrawerDataContext.Provider>
```

**LeftSidePanel Component**

```
const book= useContext(DrawerDataContext);
const open = useContext(DrawerContext);

return (
        <>

            <Drawer open={open} onClose={() => !open} anchor='left'>

                <List style={{ width: 500 }}>

                </List>
            </Drawer>
        </>
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the value of your state, you can also share a function with your context to change its value:

```
<DrawerContext.Provider value={{
  isOpen: isDrawerOpen,
  close: () => setDrawerOpen(false)
}}>
```

And in your component:

```
const book = useContext(DrawerDataContext);
const { isOpen, close } = useContext(DrawerContext);

return (
  <>
    <Drawer open={isOpen} onClose={close} anchor='left'>
      <List style={{ width: 500 }}>

      </List>
    </Drawer>
  </>
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried something similar before, but I get error:  TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isOpen' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.. Not sure why,  is because somehow button gets click and component/state is not updated?

Comment: @SharePointer Did you set the `value` of the context correctly?

Comment: yes, I think so:     <DrawerDataContext.Provider value={bookId}>
        <DrawerContext.Provider value={{
          isOpen: isDrawerOpen,
          close: () => setDrawerOpen(false)
        }} >
          <LeftSidePanel />
        </DrawerContext.Provider>
      </DrawerDataContext.Provider>

button click is :     <button onClick={() => { toggleSidePanel(row); }} >toggle drawer</button>

Comment: @SharePointer I think it's because you need to provide a default value when creating your context: `const DrawerContext = createContext({});`

Comment: I tried this no luck: export const DrawerContext = createContext({});

Comment: And you get the same error? I think you will need to reproduce the problem on a snippet so I can check your code directly.

Comment: Yes same error, I will try and create codesandbox

Comment: @SharePointer You contexts are not exported as default, so you should import them as `import { DrawerContext, DrawerDataContext } from` and not `import DrawerContext from` & `import DrawerDataContext from`

Comment: @SharePointer The initial issue of your question should be solved so please consider accepting this answer. If you have other problems, you should ask a new question.

Comment: thanks, I had the import correctly in the local code, but somehow it wasn't working but I deleted the import and restarted the server and it worked.  Strange!! thanks for your help.